# Why are some of the weights not initialized from the pretrained model checkpoint (from hugging face)?

Tags: bert, huggingface

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification

# Load tokenizer and model
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("Maltehb/danish-bert-botxo")
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("Maltehb/danish-bert-botxo")

# Text to classify
text = "Det er en god dag"

# Tokenize input text
inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt")

# Forward pass through the model
outputs = model(**inputs)

# Get predicted probabilities for each class
probs = torch.softmax(outputs.logits, dim=1).detach().numpy()

print(probs)
# Predicted label
predicted_label = "positive" if probs[0][1] > probs[0][0] else "negative"

print("positive prob:", probs[0][1])
print("negative prob:", probs[0][0])
print(f"The sentiment of the text '{text}' is {predicted_label}.")
```

output:

```
$ python temp.py 
Some weights of BertForSequenceClassification were not init
ialized from the model checkpoint at Maltehb/danish-bert-bo
txo and are newly initialized: ['classifier.bias', 'classifier.weight']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.        
[[0.43838173 0.5616182 ]]
positive prob: 0.5616182
negative prob: 0.43838173
The sentiment of the text 'Det er en god dag' is positive.
```

I am surprised to read that `Some weights of BertForSequenceClassification were not init ialized from the model checkpoint at Maltehb/danish-bert-bo txo and are newly initialized: ['classifier.bias', 'classifier.weight']`.

If I understood it correctly, [Maltehb/danish-bert-bo
txo](https://huggingface.co/Maltehb/danish-bert-botxo?text=K%C3%B8benhavn+er+%5BMASK%5D+i+Danmark.) is an already trained model, so I shouldn't have to train it again. So why were some of the weights not initialized  from the model checkpoint?

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are using a BertForSequenceClassification while the model you are using should be a BertForPreTraining.

The difference is that BertForSequenceClassification has a classifier head while the BertForPreTraining has not. Hence even if the Bert backbone use the learned weights from "danish-bert-bo", there is no weight for the classifier head in there so the classifier baias and weight remained as initialized randomly.

So replace AutoModelForSequenceClassification by AutoModelForPreTraining